# Still logged in after logging out via api guard in route closure with Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, api, nuxt.js, logout, laravel-passport

I'm logging out this way from my **Laravel** website `backend.test` via a **Nuxt** frontend on `localhost:3000`:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/logout', function (Request $request) {
    Log::info('Delete token...');
    $request->user()->token()->revoke();
});
```

I'm logged out in the frontend, the `logout` route is passed in **Laravel** (I see the `Log::info` in the logs and no error message), but when I get back to my `backend.test` and refresh, I'm still logged in.

What's wrong in my logout process ?

Comment: Why not use auth()->user()->token()->revoke(); instead?

Comment: @kelvin because it gives me the same result.

Comment: You can write logic to manually delete the token from the db, you can also try to dd $request->user()->token() and see what that gives you.